# JEST does not trigger mock functions Vue js

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I have a simple component with unit test like below. I am trying to trigger click event on anchor but I think it does not happen because of error:

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Component:

```
<template>
<a @click="fetchAll" class="icon">
            <Icon class="icon"  scale="2" />
        </a>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   methods: {
       fetchAll() {}
   }
}
</script>
```

Test:

```
it('should fetch all', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
            stubs: [ 'Icon'],
            localVue
        })

        const fetchAll = jest.fn()
        wrapper.setMethods({ fetchAll })
        wrapper.find('.icon').trigger('click')
        expect(fetchAll).toBeCalled()
    })


What is wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your component mounted correctly? Try like that:

`const fetchAllMock = jest.fn()
 wrapper.setMethods({ fetchAll: fetchAllMock  })`

Comment: what is difference?

Comment: There is no difference, sorry for my stupid assumption ... I was in a hurry. Is that actually your whole component code? I see you have multiple elements with class="icon". find() returns the wrapper of first founded element. If you have more than one element with same class name, you should use findAll() which returns array of wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in my case the fix was to call the method in the template with the parenthesis, like this:

```html
<a @click="fetchAll()" class="icon">
```

It sounds weird because in all the docs and tutorials I've seen the preferred syntax is without parenthesis (if you don't have parameters), but this is the only solution that worked.

Comment: Otherwise you can spy on the method before mounting, in this way you should be able to test the function call even without the parentheses: `const fetchAllSpy = jest.spyOn(Component.methods, 'fetchAll');
const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
            stubs: [ 'Icon'],
            localVue
        });  wrapper.find('.icon').trigger('click');
expect(fetchAllSpy).
toBeCalled();`